# Difficulty with creating a new variable in Stata using the subtraction operator

Tags: stata

I am a Stata novice.

I am having great difficulty creating this variable:

```
generate gap= 0.364 * (male − 0.707) − 0.0146 * (FVCpercent  − 66.763) + 0.131 * (age_integer − 67.676) − 0.0814 * (age_gap) + 0.0287 * (avg_fibrosis − 22.147)
```

male is numeric (male=1, female=0)
FVCpercent, age_integer, age_gap and avg_fibrosis are all numeric.

I repeatedly get this error

```
male−0.707 invalid name
```

For some reason, if I switch all the "-" operators to "+" it works.

I would be grateful for any input. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a weird error related to the character `−` that you are using. It is somewhat different from `-`(which is the correct one). I replace them, and now it works.

```
clear all
input  male FVCpercent age_integer age_gap avg_fibrosis
10 10 10 10 10 10
end

generate gap = 0.364 * (male - 0.707) - 0.0146 * (FVCpercent  - 66.763) + 0.131 * (age_integer - 67.676) - 0.0814 * (age_gap) + 0.0287 * (avg_fibrosis - 22.147)
```

Comment: This works, but I copied and pasted your solution into Stata. I cannot see the difference but clearly there is. Could you point me to the right "-" character please?

Comment: @GhostRider, here are both characters. Incorrect: `−`. Correct: `-`. I don't know how you managed to get such character, but it has happened to me sometimes when I copy-paste code from a pdf document.

Comment: Yep. You got it. I copied from a PDF. Well caught :)

Comment: In principle, minus sign, hyphen, en dash and em dash are distinct characters for printing and publishing purposes.